# What relation is she to Bill?

Tags: situation, family

Bill asked his brother’s wife’s mother-in-law’s only husband’s only daughter to join him and his wife for dinner. What relation is she to Bill?

Answer (score 10):

She is

> **his sister** because his brother’s wife’s mother-in-law’s = his mother, her only husband is Bill's father, and so his only daughter must be his sister

Comment: This is probably the intended answer, although it assumes no children born out of wedlock, and also no previous marriages for the father.

Comment: @Bass also Bill's brother could have married a widow, and her late husband's mother is still alive, while Bill's mother is not.

Comment: @Bass & deepthought Right, I assumed it wasn't intended to be a tricky question

Answer (score 0):

> She is Bill's sister.
>  Bill's brother's wife's mother in law = Bill's mother
>  Bill's mother's daughter = Bill's father's daughter = Bill's sister
>  Proved.

Comment: This answer doesn't add anything to the answer given before.

Comment: I was just explaining it more explicitly ;)

Comment: If you want to do that, it's best to edit the existing answer. :)